# Move a div to a drop position

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

Apologies in advance if I am bad at describing this problem... hope you can still understand it.

Right now I have a Div that has its display set to 'none'.
When I drag and drop a button on the screen, it will then add a class to unhide the div.

Those above work fine, but what I cannot figure out is how to have the div appear exactly at where I dropped the button, rather than always appearing at a fixed location in the middle of the screen (which is what it is doing right now).

Would appreciate any help I can get! Here is the part of the javascript I am using (please let me know if this isn't sufficient info):

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.js-hotspot').draggable({
                    helper: "clone",
                    revert: false,
                    start: function(event, ui) {
                        console.log("Started");
                    },
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        addAnyHotspot();

                        $( ".hotspot-tooltip" ).addClass( "open" ); //Unhide the div
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. This is my new code:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.js-hotspot').draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                revert: false,
                start: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log("Started");

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(this).on("drag", function(e) {
                    var x = e.pageX;
                    var y = e.pageY;
                    var el = $("#meh"); //assign #meh to the div that needs to be opened
                    el.css('position', 'absolute');
                    el.css("left", x);
                    el.css("top", y);
                    console.log("Shifted Position");
                  })
                });

                },
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    addAnyHotspot();
                    console.log("AddAnyHotSpot");

                    $( ".hotspot-tooltip" ).addClass( "open" );
                }
            });
        });
```